# Where to save variables in scene not tied to any particular GameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to keep track of some values related to the current scene eg: play time (time), last movement (time). However they are not values I need to display the user, nor are they related to any game object in particular so I'm not sure where to save them.

I need them to be persistent in the scene and also accessible to all GameObjects.

Where do I save them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way.

```
public static class Container
{
    private static int variable;
}
```

Keep a static class with the information that you require.

---

You can also use a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

```
public class Container
{
    private static Container instance;
    private int sampleVariable;

    private Container() {}

    public static Container getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
           instance = new Container();

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: would I be able to write in the static class variables?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is to designate an empty game object as a hub for scripts like those that you are describing. In all of my Unity projects, I have an empty game object called *ScriptHub* on which I attach all scripts that do not really pertain to any particular game object. Here you can keep track of any number of values and these can all be accessed by other scripts in your scene.

Comment: I was doing that I just thought that there should be a better way.

Comment: Alternatively, I guess you could maintain some static object and this static class is not attached to any game object.